# get quickbooks web connector response xml

Tags: xml, soap, quickbooks

I've been trying to figure out how to get the response xml from an Invoice Add request to determine why the invoice isn't showing on our QuickBooks Desktop App.

Here's my request XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <InvoiceAddRq requestID="1">
      <InvoiceAdd>
        <CustomerRef>
          <FullName>Jason Bourne</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <TxnDate>2016-10-18</TxnDate>
        <RefNumber>IR1-102016-00015</RefNumber>
        <BillAddress>
          <Addr1>Walt Disney World Resort</Addr1>
          <City>Orlando</City>
          <State></State>
          <PostalCode></PostalCode>
          <Country>United States</Country>
        </BillAddress>
        <PONumber></PONumber>
        <ItemSalesTaxRef>
                <FullName></FullName>
        </ItemSalesTaxRef>
        <Memo></Memo> 
        <InvoiceLineAdd>
          <ItemRef>
             <FullName>ProductName</FullName>
          </ItemRef>
          <Desc>ProductDescription</Desc>
          <Quantity>1</Quantity>
          <Rate>$100</Rate>
        </InvoiceLineAdd>

      </InvoiceAdd>
    </InvoiceAddRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The QWCLog.txt shows we sent it successfully to QB and got a response.

```
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Received from sendRequestXML() following parameter:
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : strRequestXML =
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
......

20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_sendRequestXML() : Request xml received.
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Processing request #1
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : REQUEST: received from application: size (bytes) = 994
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending request to QuickBooks.
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Response received from QuickBooks: size (bytes) = 245
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ProcessRequestXML() : Sending response back to application.
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : *** Calling receiveResponseXML() with following parameters:
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : wcTicket="9b9bc911-e40c-44be-8198-442c65d34585"
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : response =
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : XML dump follows: -

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<InvoiceAddRs requestID="1" st......

20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""
20161123.14:32:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""
20161123.14:33:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : Received from receiveResponseXML() following parameters:
20161123.14:33:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : more="100">
20161123.14:33:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : Done. No more to process.
```

Tried getting the "response" params but that was empty. Did I miss something on my InvoiceAddRq requestxml?

Dev Environment Specs:
QuickBooks Premier Non-Profit Edition Trial Version 2014
QuickBooks Web Connector version 2.1.0.30

UPDATE:

Here's the code implementation for the receiveResponseXML:

The web method that receives the call.

```
public SendResponseXMLResponse receiveResponseXML(RecieveResponseXML sendResponseXmlSoapIn)
    {
        var sendRequestXmlResponse = new SendResponseXMLResponse();
        //get the qbxml response here...
        sendRequestXmlResponse.ReceiveResponseXMLResult.Add("100"); //100  means 100% complete tells QWC to close connection

        return sendRequestXmlResponse;
    }
```

The response object model:

```
[DataContract(Name = "receiveResponseXML")]
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "receiveResponseXML", IsWrapped = true)]
public class RecieveResponseXML
{
    [DataMember(Name = "wcTicket", IsRequired = true)]
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "wcTicket", Order = 1)]
    public string WCTicket { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "response ", IsRequired = true)]
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "response ", Order = 2)]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "hresult ", IsRequired = true)]
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "hresult ", Order = 3)]
    public string Hresult { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message ", IsRequired = true)]
    [MessageBodyMember(Name = "message ", Order = 4)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public RecieveResponseXML()
    {
    }

    public RecieveResponseXML(string wcTicket, string response, string hresult, string message)
    {
        this.WCTicket = wcTicket;
        this.Response = response;
        this.Hresult = hresult;
        this.Message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your code/implementation? Specifically, the implementation of y our receiveResponseXML method which will receive the response from QuickBooks?

Comment: Does QB have it's own logging that we can also check?

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how it was supposed to be setup on Web Connector version 2.1.0.30 but I just downloaded the QuickBooks Pro/Premier 2016 Trial and used Web Connector 2.2.0.34. I can now see the full receiveResponseXML xml dump that shows what the error was. It appears that the value for <RefNumber> was too long.

My Webservice is still not getting that xml dump though.

Comment: QuickBooks does not have any logging here. You can set the Web Connector to VERBOSE mode and it'll show you more detail (including the full XML). I think you should post your full code so we can actually test/help you debug this.